# What is $$ and $x in Chrome Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I saw Chrome's autocomplete suggestions when I was testing JQuery and saw `$$` and `$x` are defined. What are they and where did they come from? I saw [What is the variable $x used for in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661949/what-is-the-variable-x-used-for-in-chrome), but what is `$$`?

```
> $
  function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } jquery.js?body=1:62
> $$
  function $$() { [Command Line API] }
> $x
  function $x() { [Command Line API] }
```

This is something [ogooglebar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogooglebar#Ungoogleable).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector_1

Comment: Sorry, jumped the gun a bit on the close vote, that one only covers `$x()`. symbolhound is a good place to start looking for things like this: http://symbolhound.com/?q=webkit+%24%24

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`$$(selector)`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector_1):

> Returns an array of elements that match the given CSS selector. This
>   command is equivalent to calling `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same question. From the link Ast Derek posted, it looks like the following objects exist by default:

```
$() is an alias for document.querySelector()
$$() is an alias for document.querySelectorAll()
```

I've checked both Chrome and Firefox, and these seem to be true for both.

When you link jQuery, $() gets replaced by the jQuery object, but $$() still exists with its default behavior. Pretty confusing for someone who is new to all of this stuff.

Comment: Great answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is also **$x()** function for those who want to use xpath

e.g.

```
$x("//div")
```

*for xpath syntax see : https://devhints.io/xpath*