# Missing error after argument list - Selenium Python (executing Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I've been at this for a while now, I know there are some questions along the lines of this one but I cannot figure out where on earth my string isn't escaped correctly or needs more quotes.

I have this line

```
self.driver.execute_script("$x('//div[text()=\'Find Artwork\']')[0].click()")
```

and this works perfectly in the console

```
$x('//div[text()=\'Find Artwork\']')[0].click()
```

However when running in Python with Selenium + Chrome webdriver I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

Unsure quite what to do here. I've tried double quotes, escaping, everything.

Thanks!

Comment: driver.execute_script("$x('//div[text()=\"Find Artwork\"]')[0].click()") Maybe try this.

Answer (score 0):

`$x` is not part of JavaScript, but just a utility in cosole of firefox and chrome.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661949/what-is-the-variable-x-used-for-in-chrome).

You can try something like this:

```py
javaScript = "document.getElementsById('username')[0].click();"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)

//or

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element);
```